# How does SQL Server select the 'join' strategy

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, nested

In SQL Server I have two inputs for 'join '，the amount of first input is 400000.When the amount of second input is 3W~4w, the query is efficient, but if the amount of second input reduce to 2000~3000, the query needs a long time to process. I investigate the execute plan for the twice query. I find when the hotpot is nested loop join when the second input is 2000~3000.

The two inputs are all the temp table not variable table because I know the variable table doesn't has 'statistical'.

So I  don't know why the SQL Server choose nested loop join, or How does Sqlserver select the join poliy? I find some explain in MSDN, but it tillIf one join input is small (fewer than 10 rows) and the other join input is fairly large and indexed on its join columns, an index nested loops join is the fastest join operation because they require the least I/O and the fewest comparisons.'

[Efficient Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJGhy.png)

[Slow Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36YA2.png)

I try to find something like 'How does Sqlserver select the join poliy',but I didn't get something.

Comment: Please share the query plans via https://pastetheplan.com, the screenshots are useless. Also please show your actual query, along with all relevant tables *and index* definitions. This question is not answerable without this information

Comment: what's "3w - 4w"? it looks like your tables doesn't have any primary keys / indexes, maybe can start with that?

Comment: @siggemannen  1w is 10k in the Chinese dialect of English, OP I guess this is what you mean? I have difficulty understanding much of yours. better use common English or modern machine translation.